# How to get all the values of an enum with typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, enums

Given an a TypeScript enum:

```
export enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
}
```

I want to get all its values in an array like so:

```
["Red", "Green", "Blue"]
```

Yet when I work on that enum with

```
const colors = Object.keys(Color);
```

I get weird array consisting of its index and value:

```
[ '0', '1', '2', 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue' ]
```

Why is this the case and how can I only get the values?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You have to filter out the numeric keys, either via `Object.values` or `Object.keys`:

```
const colors = Object.keys(Color).filter((item) => {
    return isNaN(Number(item));
});
console.log(colors.join("\n"));
```

This will print:

```
Red
Green
Blue
```

A TypeScript enum will transpile in the end into a plain JavaScript object:

```
{ 
  '0': 'Red', 
  '1': 'Green',
  '2': 'Blue',
  Red: 0,
  Green: 1,
  Blue: 2
}
```

So you can use the numeric index as key to get the value, and you can use the value to lookup its index in the enum:

```
console.log(Color[0]); // "Red"
console.log(Color["0"]); // "Red"
console.log(Color["Red"]) // 0
```

Comment: why not just write `Object.values(Color)`

Comment: @pavle `Object.values` is part of ECMAScript 2017. The `Object.keys` is part of ECMAScript 2015 / ES5.

Comment: @pavle Added it to my answer, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Like @k0pernikus said, TypeScript enums is compiled in a way it allows to lookup to an index from a value. So `Object.keys` and `Object.values` return an array with same values (regardless the type). I use `Object.keys(Color).filter(k => isNaN(Number(k)));` to get my enum keys list.

Comment: Actually, Object.values(Color) could return a key if the value is a number and your enum is a string. Example: ` enum StringEnum {
  First = 'First Value',
  Second = 'Second Value',
  Third = 4
} ` would return `Third` with the values.

Comment: Object.values(COLLECTIONS).filter(isNaN as any)

Comment: Can't post another answer here and the linked "duplicate" is a different question. Here's k0pernikus's method wrapped into a generic function: [How to get an array of enum values in TypeScript](https://blog.oyam.dev/typescript-enum-values/)

Comment: Object.values() is superior because it returns the correct type, whereas Object.keys() returns type string[].