# VS Code extension with webpack and link to node_modules

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, webpack, webview, vscode-extensions

I created a VS Code extension which uses a [Webview](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview). In the Webview I have a link to a file in the `node_modules` folder which I added to the html as recommended by various sources (e.g. [vscode-codicons-sample](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/webview-codicons-sample)):

```
const codiconsUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
  Uri.joinPath(this.context.extensionUri, 'node_modules', '@vscode/codicons', 'dist', 'codicon.css')
);
```

and in the html:

```
<link href="${codiconsUri}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now I'd like to use webpack for bundling. I followed the instructions from Visual Studio Code [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/bundling-extension#migrate-an-existing-extension).

In the `.vscodeignore` file I exclude the `node_modules` folder as instructed. (That's the main reason for bundling)

And when I package the project now, of course, the `node_modules` is not present in the .vsix file and thus the Uri is invalid.

How would you solve that? (I use this method to insert many more links besides codicons)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could copy that file into an own folder, which gets packaged with the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with @MikeLischke's suggestion and copy the required files into the `dist` folder, which is packaged. But I didn't want to do it manually, so I did the following.

### NodeModulesAccessor

Firstly, I created a class which does the mapping between the files in the `node_modules` folder and the destination in the packaged `dist` folder.

```js
import { NodeModulesKeys } from './nodeModulesKeys';
import { NodeModulesValue } from './nodeModulesValue';

export class NodeModulesAccessor {
  static readonly outputPath = 'dist';

  private static readonly pathMapping = new Map<NodeModulesKeys, NodeModulesValue>([
    [
      NodeModulesKeys.ffmpegMinJs,
      {
        sourcePath: ['node_modules', '@ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg', 'dist'],
        destinationPath: ['libs', '@ffmpeg', 'ffmpeg', 'dist'],
        fileName: 'ffmpeg.min.js',
      },
    ],
    [
      NodeModulesKeys.ffmpegCoreJs,
      {
        sourcePath: ['node_modules', '@ffmpeg', 'core', 'dist'],
        destinationPath: ['libs', '@ffmpeg', 'core', 'dist'],
        fileName: 'ffmpeg-core.js',
        includeFolder: true,
      },
    ],
    [
      NodeModulesKeys.codiconCss,
      {
        sourcePath: ['node_modules', '@vscode', 'codicons', 'dist'],
        destinationPath: ['libs', '@vscode', 'codicons', 'dist'],
        fileName: 'codicon.css',
        includeFolder: true,
      },
    ],
  ]);

  static getPathToOutputFile(key: NodeModulesKeys): string[] {
    const path = this.getMappedValue(key);
    return [this.outputPath, ...path.destinationPath, path.fileName];
  }

  static getPathToNodeModulesFile(key: NodeModulesKeys): NodeModulesValue {
    return this.getMappedValue(key);
  }

  private static getMappedValue(key: NodeModulesKeys): NodeModulesValue {
    const value = this.pathMapping.get(key);
    if (!value) {
      throw Error(`Path to "${key}" is not mapped.`);
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

`NodeModulesKeys` is a simple enum of all the files I want to use:

```js
export enum NodeModulesKeys {
  ffmpegMinJs,
  ffmpegCoreJs,
  codiconCss,
}
```

and `NodeModulesValue` is an interface:

```js
export interface NodeModulesValue {
  sourcePath: string[];
  destinationPath: string[];
  fileName: string;
  includeFolder?: boolean;
}
```

Some libraries (e.g. codicons) require multiple files inside the folder. That is why `NodeModulesValue` has an optional field `includeFolder`.

### webpack.config.ts

Here is where the magic happens (don't worry, it's not that complicated).

You can use the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) to copy files while bundling:

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import { NodeModulesAccessor } from './src/node-modules-accessor/nodeModulesAccessor';
import { NodeModulesKeys } from './src/node-modules-accessor/nodeModulesKeys';
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';
import CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config: Configuration = {
  // omitted, nothing special here
  plugins: [copyNodeModulesFiles()],
};

function copyNodeModulesFiles(): CopyPlugin {
  const files: NodeModulesKeys[] = Object.keys(NodeModulesKeys)
    .filter((key) => !isNaN(Number(key)))
    .map((key) => Number(key));
  const copies: CopyPlugin.ObjectPattern[] = files.map((file) => {
    const value = NodeModulesAccessor.getPathToNodeModulesFile(file);
    let sourcePath;
    let destinationPath;
    if (value.includeFolder) {
      sourcePath = path.join(...value.sourcePath);
      destinationPath = path.join(...value.destinationPath);
    } else {
      sourcePath = path.join(...value.sourcePath, value.fileName);
      destinationPath = path.join(...value.destinationPath, value.fileName);
    }
    return {
      from: sourcePath,
      to: destinationPath,
    };
  });
  return new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: copies,
  });
}

module.exports = config;
```

Here we iterate over all the values of the `NodeModulesKeys` enum. ([How to iterate over enum values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48768775)) and add a copy instruction for each of them.

We can also copy entire folders if we need to.

### Webview integration

To get the Uris and use them in the webview html, we use the `NodeModulesAccessor` again.

```js
const codiconsUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
  Uri.joinPath(this.context.extensionUri, ...NodeModulesAccessor.getPathToOutputFile(NodeModulesKeys.codiconCss))
);
```

#### Important

For the webview to be able to access the `dist/libs` directory, you have define the directory as a `localResourceRoot` when you create the webview:

```js
this.viewPanel = window.createWebviewPanel('sampleId', 'Sample Webview', ViewColumn.Beside, {
  enableScripts: true,
  retainContextWhenHidden: true,
  localResourceRoots: [
    Uri.joinPath(this.context.extensionUri, NodeModulesAccessor.outputPath, 'libs'), // <--- Important
    Uri.joinPath(this.context.extensionUri, 'media'),
  ],
});
```

I hope that will come in handy for someone else.